# How to configure Spring security white list in filter chain properly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-filter

I'm trying to build a security filter chain and allow for some white lists to pass without security

This is my dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.1.5'
```

My filter

```java
private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URL = {"/ping/getEnvironment"};

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL)
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to build security filter chain", e);
        }
    }
```

And my test

```java
@Test
    void getEnvironmentTest() throws Exception {
        String rawResponse = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/ping/getEnvironment"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status()
                        .isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        PingResponse pingResponse = objectMapper.readValue(rawResponse, PingResponse.class);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(pingResponse);
    }
```

But this thest fails

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Unauthorized
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", WWW-Authenticate:"Basic realm="Realm"", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

As you can see I'm getting 401 instead of 200

Comment: you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is unsecure, and thats why there is no such implementation in spring security. Writing a custom security solution is also bad practice. It is quite obvious that you just learnt from a tutorial and did not read the spring security documentation before asking here. Please remove your custom filter, read the docs and build security properly without handing out JWTs to browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Regarding JWTs in Spring Security, they can be used securely in browsers, as supported by official resources like jwt.io.

I've consulted Spring Security docs and my use case involves stateless authentication post-login. Any advice on achieving this within Spring Security with JWTs?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction

This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that are permitted with that token

Comment: i have read the entire thing and nowhere does it say that handing out jwts to browsers is fine. So where in the text does it say that it is okey? On the other hand it says `You also should not store sensitive session data in browser storage due to lack of security.` so __where in the text does it say that its fine to use jwts in browsers__. The text you are referring to is mobile clients, and applications, as in desktop applications.

Comment: i suggest you read redis: https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/ okta: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens spring teams guidlines for SPA applications https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297 OWASPs considerations on JWTS https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#consideration-about-using-jwt Oauth2 implicit flow (Handing out tokens to clients) is NOT RECOMMENDED https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-8.2

Comment: _I've consulted Spring Security docs and my use case involves stateless authentication post-login_ which can be achived by implementing a separate issuer, as in keycloak, spring authorization server, curity etc. And building a BFF pattern, which means that your frontend talks to your BFF, the browser is redirected to the issuer, and then riderected back with a code that is exchanged for a JWT token that is stored in the backend, while the backend issues a cookie to the browser. Logging in and issuing a JWT straight to the browser is insecure, and that is why there is no such implementation.

Comment: I appreciate your insights on JWT usage. Regarding our discussion:
JWTs can be secure in browsers without exposing sensitive info.
My integration needs endpoint protection and whitelisting.
A token is required for endpoint access, regardless of the client.
Extensive comments led to a discussion somewhat divergent from the main query.
The tutorialachieves the desired functionality but lacks step-wise clarity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxqlJblhzfI&t=5267s)
Let's keep the discussion focused on finding a working solution please. Appreciate help refining my implementation.

Comment: `JWTs can be secure in browsers without exposing sensitive info` please explain how? The tutorial linked is filled with bad practices and should be taken down from the internet but the creator of the tutorial is more interested in views than actually building secure applications. `a token is needed for enpoint access` is just a completely wrong statement. Its quite clear that you have no interest at all to actually learn proper security. I have no informed you that you have built a insecure application, thats all im going to do since you also dont seem to have an interest in good security

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I was missing the @Bean annotation.
After adding the `@Bean` my test passed as expected

This is how my security filter chahin looks like including the filter anotation.

```java
package eu.vxbank.api.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider; // from spring
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter; // my filter

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URL = {"/ping/getEnvironment"};

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL)
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to build security filter chain", e);
        }
    }
}
```